# Is there a way to select multiple rows and append one row of the most recent entry to this original query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to query a database of CRM users, the table is called **crm_main**.  Let's just say that there are 3 users in this table for the sake of making this easier to explain.  I have another table called **crm_comments** which stores multiple comments for each user with a timestamp.

Is there a way to select all of the users in crm_main and IF a comment exists in the crm_comments table, append the most recent one (based on the timestamp) to the row? I've tried using a CROSS APPLY method:

```
SELECT  *
FROM crm_main d
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 timestamp, customerid
        FROM crm_comments m
        WHERE m.customerid = d.id
        ORDER BY
                m.timestamp DESC
        ) m
```

The problem with this is that it only returns the user from the crm_main table if a comment in the crm_comments table exists for them.  So if user id 1 and 3 have comments associated with them in the crm_comments table, they'll show, but the user with no comment (user id 2) will not show.  Is there a way to query them up anyway and just show NULL for the timestamp?

This way all 3 will show, but id#1 and id#3 will have timestamps and id#2 will just have NULL.

Perhaps there is a way to do this with a CASE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [OUTER APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT  *
FROM crm_main d
OUTER APPLY
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 timestamp, customerid
        FROM crm_comments m
        WHERE m.customerid = d.id
        ORDER BY
                m.timestamp DESC
        ) m;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b259/2)

From MSDN:

> OUTER APPLY returns both rows that produce a result set, and rows that do not, with NULL values in the columns produced by the table-valued function.

Comment: This did it - very detailed answer. Thank you!